# Вычисление среднего арифметического через Javascript

Tags: html, javascript

Есть код HTML:

> `<table>
> <tbody>
> <tr>
> <td><span>4</span></td>
> <td></td>
> <td><span>5</span></td>
> <td><span>4</span></td>
> <td><span>4</span></td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
> <td><span>ИТОГ</span></td>
> </tr>
> </tbody>
> </table>`

Как здесь можно вычесть среднее арифметическое через Javascript и записать его, где написано 'ИТОГ'?

Comment: @Никита___, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: При чём здесь учёба и среднее арифметическое полученных чисел? Я записываю числа, а из них должно быть вычтено среднее арифметическое.

Comment: Может просто DOM заформировать, не? Ведь редко когда статика в тупую так рисуется, а потом парсится JS'ом.

Обычно этим вообще backend занимается, а JS тут лишний будет.

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое DOM или BACKEND. Мой сайт написан только на HTML, Javascript и JQouery. Поэтому я и спросил, как это сделать через Javascript.

Comment: Oh sh...

Ну ок, вот лучше почитай про DOM(Document Object Model) http://javascript.ru/tutorial/dom

Там тебе подробнее расскажут с примерами, чем если я тебе буду описывать здесь.

Без DOM ты это не сделаешь, вернее тебе либо парсить DOM и записывать в результат, либо формировать DOM целиком вместе с результатом.

В общем по сути DOM это твоя html'ка, но это если очень вычурно описать.

Comment: Ааа, ясно. DOM то мне понятен, я просто поначалу не понял что вы имели ввиду @deterok. Короче, я задал этот вопрос, потому что не хочу приписывать для каждого столбца ID, складывать их, вычитывать и т.д. У меня их около ста в таблице, и сами понимаете, что для каждого столбца делать переменные и ID адреса - это ересь. Мне поэтому и нужен другой вариант.

Comment: @Никита___, вы ставите задание в таком виде, как будто мы его должны с нуля решить. Покажите, что вы пытались сделать. Мы подтолкнем на путь истинный. Здесь за это не пинают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён здесь:

[Функция ".replace()" в "document.getElementsByTagName().innerText". Вычисление среднего арифметич...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/400835/javascript-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-replace-%D0%B2-document-getelementsbytagname-innertext-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87)

Answer (score 1):

Держи

```
  <table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td ><span class="var">4</span></td>
<td></td>
<td ><span class="var">5</span></td>
<td ><span class="var">4</span></td>
<td ><span class="var">4</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="itog"></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
var sum = 0;
$('.var').each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text());  
});

$('.itog').text(sum);
</script>
```

Comment: и какой смысл тут у классов .var, как будто, без них нельзя пройтись по ячейкам таблицы. и записать вместо слова итог. ТС вроде как не желает прописывать каждой ячейке доп класс или id

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко, то нужно каждой ячейке присвоить стиль, затем при помощи jQuery выдернуть все элементы с этим стилем, пройтись по ним и посчитать среднее. За конкретными функциями - плиз, в документацию, заодно хоть узнаете, что jQuery умеет.