# Функция ".replace()" в "document.getElementsByTagName().innerText". Вычисление среднего арифметич...

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Есть страница:

http://jsfiddle.net/5sfffykr/3/

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так с кодом Javascript? Почему не высчитывается средний балл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё потому, что вы получаете набор элементов функцией

```
getElementsByTagName()
```

Она содержит массив элементов.

```
for(var s =0; s < spAA.length; s++) {
    console.log(spAA[s]);

    spA = spAA[s].textContent.replace(/[н\-]/g, "");

    for (i=0; i<spA.length; i++) {
        t += parseInt(spA, 10);
    }
}
```

Плюс советую не использовать `innerText()`, т.к. это не стандартная функция.

Comment: var text = el.innerText || el.textContent; - и никаких проблем